# C++ timer class not compiling, I don't see why

Tags: c++

There is a great timer class for C++ that I wanted to use on Windows:

http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html

http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/files/timer.zip

However, when I try to build it on VS2010, it tells me that for example "endCount" is not declared.

However, I can see that it is.

The section "#ifded WIN32" is not greyed out, so I guess this section is "in reach" and executed.

```
#ifdef WIN32
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;                    // ticks per second
    LARGE_INTEGER startCount;                   //
    LARGE_INTEGER endCount;                     //
```

I guess there is something broken in general, but I don't see what.

Can somebody perhaps take a look at the project and see why might the error?

Here is a part of the cpp:

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// constructor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Timer::Timer()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    startCount.QuadPart = 0;
    endCount.QuadPart = 0;
#else
    startCount.tv_sec = startCount.tv_usec = 0;
    endCount.tv_sec = endCount.tv_usec = 0;
#endif

    stopped = 0;
    startTimeInMicroSec = 0;
    endTimeInMicroSec = 0;
}
```

And this is the header:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H_DEF
#define TIMER_H_DEF

#ifdef WIN32   // Windows system specific
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#else          // Unix based system specific
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif


class Timer
{
public:
    Timer();                                    // default constructor
    ~Timer();                                   // default destructor

    void   start();                             // start timer
    void   stop();                              // stop the timer
    double getElapsedTime();                    // get elapsed time in second
    double getElapsedTimeInSec();               // get elapsed time in second (same as getElapsedTime)
    double getElapsedTimeInMilliSec();          // get elapsed time in milli-second
    double getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();          // get elapsed time in micro-second


protected:


private:
    double startTimeInMicroSec;                 // starting time in micro-second
    double endTimeInMicroSec;                   // ending time in micro-second
    int    stopped;                             // stop flag 
#ifdef WIN32
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;                    // ticks per second
    LARGE_INTEGER startCount;                   //
    LARGE_INTEGER endCount;                     //
#else
    timeval startCount;                         //
    timeval endCount;                           //
#endif
};

#endif // TIMER_H_DEF
```

Comment: Could you quote the exact errors you are getting. It does help us if you do this.

Comment: "endCount is not defined".

Comment: above we only see the `declaration` of endCount, can you show us the `definition`?

Comment: @tmighty Try cutting and pasting **the whole error message** including file names, line numbers etc. Good Grief!

Comment: ok, you linked the timer class. can you now link your usage of it? My suspicion is, that you might have missed a piece of code somewhere. Usually initialization.

Comment: The library actually includes `stdafx.h`, and it doesn't do so at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @chris In the original project, stdafx.h was not included. When I tried to compile it, the compiler told me "Unexpected file end during search for precompiled header. Did you forget to state "#include "StdAfx.h"?" That is why I included it. But then the trouble started, and endCount for example was "not defined" anymore.

Comment: @chris Sorry, I forget where the trouble actually started. That actually was the initial problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VC, everything before `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored. Include `Timer.h` and `stdlib.h` after `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 2):

The `#include "stdafx.h"` should always be the first include in the .cpp file. Includes before it will be skipped by the compiler, because it assumes those are part of the precompiled header.

Comment: That's somehow evil of VC.

Comment: @scones, I've always hated the precompiled header system.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, disable inclusion of precompiled header.

In Project properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers.

Set "Create/Use Precompiled Header" to "Not Using Precompiled Headers".